# How to represent stride and pointer arguments of glVertexAttribPointer for struct of arrays in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vbo, vao

I am having difficulty to draw vertices from a structure-of-array like data structure. I think it might be the way I am using the stride and pointer arguments in `glVertexAttribPointer`  call. I have a structure like this:

```
struct RadarReturn_t
{
    float32_t x;
    float32_t y;
    float32_t z;
    float32_t prob;
}
```

And I am using `RadarReturn_t` in another struct like this:

```
struct Detections_t
{
    uint32_t currentScanNum;
    std::array<RadarReturn_t, 64> detections;
}
```

Lets assume I want to draw a 100 of `Detections_t`. I have created one VBO to pack all of this information like this:

```
        glGenBuffers(1, &mRadarVbo);
        for (uint32_t iScan = 0; iScan < mMaxNumScans; ++iScan)
        {
            // Set the timestamp to 0U
            mPersistentDetections.at(iScan).currentScanNum = 0U;

            for (uint32_t iDet = 0; iDet < 64; ++iDet)
            {
                RadarReturn_t& detection = mPersistentDetections.at(iScan).detections.at(iDet);
                detection.x              = 0.0F;
                detection.y              = 0.0F;
                detection.z              = 0.0F;
                detection.probability    = 0.0F;
            }
        }

        // Bind the VBO and copy the initial data to the graphics card
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mRadarVbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                            mMaxNumScans * sizeof(DetectionData_t),
                            &mPersistentDetections,
                            GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

Where `mPersistentDetections` is:
`std::array<DetectionData_t, mMaxNumScans> mPersistentDetections;`

Later on in my code, I update the buffer with new incoming data like this for `currentScanNum`:

```
// Offset is: 64 Radar returns plus one scanNumber
uint32_t offset = scanNum* ((64*sizeof(RadarReturn_t)) + 1*sizeof(GLuint));
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset , sizeof(GLuint), &mPersistentDetections.at(scanNum).currentScanNum)
```

and like this for `detections`:

```
uint32_t dataSize = 64 * sizeof(RadarReturn_t);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                offset + sizeof(GLuint),
                dataSize,
                &mPersistentDetections.at(scanNum).detections);
```

This is how I represent the VAO:

```
    // Bind the VAO
    glBindVertexArray(mRadarVao);

    // Specify the layout of timestamp data
    glVertexAttribIPointer(0,
                           1,
                           GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                           sizeof(DetectionData_t),
                           (GLvoid*) 0);

    // Specify the layout of the radar return data
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,
                          4,
                          GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(DetectionData_t),
                          (GLvoid*) (sizeof(GLuint)));
```

And finally the draw call:

`glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mMaxNumScans* 64);`

If I am drawing this for `mMaxNumScans = 100` am not able to draw 100x64 vertices here for some reason. Can you please point me out where I am going wrong?

---

**EDIT:**
As per suggestion from @Rabbid76, I have modified the `Detections_t` struct as follows:

```
struct Detections_t
{    
    std::array<RadarReturn_t, 64> detections;
    std::array<uint32_t, 64> scanNumbers;
}
```

I have also appropriately modified `glBufferData` and `glBufferSubData` calls. And here is where I am still having an issue. I am not able to get the correct stride argument.

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                      mDetectionAttributeSize,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      sizeof(RadarReturn_t),
                      reinterpret_cast<void*>offsetof(DetectionData_t, detectionData_t::detections)));


glVertexAttribIPointer(1,
                       mTimestampAttributeSize,
                       GL_INT,
                       sizeof(RadarReturn_t),
                       reinterpret_cast<void*>(offsetof(DetectionData_t, DetectionData_t::scanCounter)));
```

If I set the stride of attribute 0 to `sizeof(Detection_t)`, not all the points will be drawn. Only `sizeof(RadarReturn_t)` draws all the points.

And if I set the stride of attribute 1 to `sizeof(Detection_t)` the color (I am using the scanNumber to vary the alpha value) of the detections becomes transparent after only a few scans.

I would appreciate if someone can tell me what the stride value is supposed to be in this case for attribute 0 and attribute 1.

Comment: The vertices and its attributes are tuples. Hence the number of array elements has to be the same for each attribute. You cannot generate permutations of attributes. In your implementation for attribute 0 are specified 100 elements, but for attribute 1 are specified 64*100 elements. This is not possibel. You have to specify 100*64 elements for attribute 0, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yeah I thought that might be the case, but I am glad to get an outside opinion on this. I would love to hear an efficient way to implement what I want without having to create redundant attribute 0 elements.

Comment: Why do you need two buffers when your data is stored in one array with all attributes occupying the same contiguous region of memory? Just *use the stride* correctly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I am using one VBO.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my question. I was able to get it working properly by changing the `RadarReturn_t` struct like this:

```
struct RadarReturn_t
{
    float32_t x;
    float32_t y;
    float32_t z;
    float32_t prob;
    int32_t   scanCounter;
};
```

And then using the attributes like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0,
                      4,
                      GL_FLOAT,
                      GL_FALSE,
                      sizeof(RadarReturn_t),
                      nullptr));

glVertexAttribIPointer(1,
                       1,
                       GL_INT,
                       sizeof(RadarReturn_t),
                       (void*) (4 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT)));
```

Comment: `sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` takes the size of the integer that holds the symbolic constant for GL_FLOAT. You want `sizeof(float)` instead.